# Power Query: Index for each new set of elements in a column

Tags: powerquery

I have a column in a table that indicates a group identification and I would like to generate an index that goes from 1 to the number of times that group appears, for each of the groups. And then of course there are other columns with data

Example:

[image: Example table]

So, how do I generate the Index column from the Group ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click Group ID, Group By, keep name, use operation All Rows

Change the code in the window from

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each _, type table ....
```

to

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}})
```

Expand using arrows atop column

Comment: This is nothing short of magic to me!